# How can i report to the backgroundworker progresschanged event in real time the number of directories?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In this two methods GetDirectories and MyGetDirectories i'm getting recursive all the directories and sub directories. I want to display on label2 in the progresschanged event like a counter that count the number of directories until it finish.

```
private void  _FileInformationWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            MySubDirectories = GetDirectories(BasePath).ToArray();
        }

        private void _FileInformationWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Then the GetDirectories method

```
private List<DirectoryInfo> GetDirectories(string basePath)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> str = MyGetDirectories(basePath);

            List<DirectoryInfo> l = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
            l.Add(new DirectoryInfo(basePath));

            IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> dirs = str.Select(a => new DirectoryInfo(a));
            l.AddRange(dirs);

            return l;
        }
```

And the method MyGetDirectories

```
private static IEnumerable<string> MyGetDirectories(string basePath)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(basePath);
                return dirs.Union(dirs.SelectMany(dir => MyGetDirectories(dir)));
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            }
        }
```

What I tried is in the method MyGetDirectories I added a counter called the variable countDirectories and I checked it does count.

```
static int countDirectories = 0;
        private static IEnumerable<string> MyGetDirectories(string basePath)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(basePath);
                countDirectories = countDirectories + dirs.Length;
                return dirs.Union(dirs.SelectMany(dir => MyGetDirectories(dir)));
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            }
        }
```

Then in the DoWork event I did:

```
private void  _FileInformationWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            MySubDirectories = GetDirectories(BasePath).ToArray();
            _FileInformationWorker.ReportProgress(0,countDirectories.ToString());
        }
```

And in the progresschanged event

```
private void _FileInformationWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label2.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
        }
```

But it's not reporting to the label2 anything I guess since it's still working inside the GetDirectories method. So i'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code of form with just button and label on it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        DirectoryInfo[] MySubDirs;
        BackgroundWorker w;
        int count;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            count = 0;
            w = new BackgroundWorker();
            w.DoWork += w_DoWork;
            w.ProgressChanged += w_ProgressChanged;
            w.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            w.RunWorkerCompleted += w_RunWorkerCompleted;
            w.RunWorkerAsync();

        }

        void w_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }

        void w_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
        }

        void w_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            MySubDirs = GetDirectories("d:\\prj").ToArray();
        }

        private List<DirectoryInfo> GetDirectories(string basePath)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> str = MyGetDirectories(basePath);

            List<DirectoryInfo> l = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
            l.Add(new DirectoryInfo(basePath));

            IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> dirs = str.Select(a => new DirectoryInfo(a));
            l.AddRange(dirs);

            return l;
        }
        //not static so we can report progress from it
        private IEnumerable<string> MyGetDirectories(string basePath)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(basePath);
                count += dirs.Length;
                w.ReportProgress(0, count.ToString());
                return dirs.Union(dirs.SelectMany(dir => MyGetDirectories(dir)));
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: shibormot thanks I will mark it as answer. I have another question but not sure if to open for it a new question. The reporting of the number of directories is working now. But what if I wanted to report the directories them self to the variable MySubDirs in real time ? I mean now in your code and in my code we need to wait for the getting the directories to finish then MySubDirs is not null and have the directories inside. But since i'm using another backgroundworker to work over the MySubDirs.

Comment: Maybe somehow to report and fill the MysubDirs with already directories that I got. What i'm doing is looping over the directories in MySubDirs in another backgroundworker and search in this directories that are in MySubDirs. I wonder how can I start the second backjgroundworker and working on MySubDirs before the first backgroundworker finish the process.

Comment: It is better to ask new question, as it will be not a short answer

Comment: I will ask a new question with my code as it's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the following to true:

```
_FileInformationWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

Also make sure you start the work asynchronously as following:

```
_FileInformationWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) example should help you with your task as well.

Comment: I set it already. The solution was to move the ReportProgress line: _FileInformationWorker.ReportProgress to inside the MyGetDirectories method just after the line that update the counter: countDirectories = countDirectories + dirs.Length;
 and now it's working.